# how to access outer class states in inside of other class constructor function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, tradingview-api

I am having issue in accessing the TvWidget class states and proper in inside of Rsi Indicator constructor function, when i try to access it gives me undefined i removed other code this is just for context to understand the problem
in this code i am adding new custom indicator in trading view charting library for that i want to access the current ticker and index that is selected by user in library and i am having these in outer class but in inside of this constructor function i get nothing

```
const { Content } = Layout;

//Global state handling
const mapStateToProps = (state) => (
{
  currentStock: state.currentStock.currentStock,
  currentLanguage: state.currentLanguage.currentLanguage,
  currentTheme: state.currentTheme.currentTheme,
  stockType: state.stockType.stockType,
  userId: state.auth.user?.username,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { updateStock, updateTheme, updateStockType };
class TVChartContainer extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showLeftPanel: false,
      showRightPanel: false,
      selectedDate: new Date(),
      selectedLimit: "daily",
      showHistoryTable: false,
      showBottomPanel: true,
      showBottomHalf: false,
      showBottomFull: false,
      currentStock: this.props.currentStock,
      currentTheme: this.props.currentTheme,
      currentLanguage: this.props.currentLanguage,
      isZoomIn: true,
      showScreener: false,
      currentInterval: "D",
      selectedFilter: {},
      chartHeight: window.innerHeight - 230,
      userId: this.props.userId,
      load_last_chart: true,
      currentAction: "",
      currentTrader: "",
      kuzzleData: [],
      stockType: this.props.stockType,
    };
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    symbol: "1050",
    interval: "D",
    containerId: "tv_chart_container",
    datafeedUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
    libraryPath: "/charting_library/",
    chartsStorageUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
    chartsStorageApiVersion: "1.1",
    clientId: "tradingview.com",
    userId: "public_user_id",
    fullscreen: false,
    autosize: true,
    theme: "Dark",
    timezone: "Asia/Riyadh",
  };
  tvWidget = null;



  componentDidMount() {
    let location = window.location.search;

    if (location.includes("action")) {
      let action = location.split("=")[1];
      this.setState({ currentAction: action });
      this.handleShowScreener(true);
    }

    if (window.Tawk_API) {
      window.Tawk_API.hideWidget();
    }

    this.chartReady(undefined);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor =
      this.props.currentTheme === "Dark" ? "#12161F" : "#FFFFFF";
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.props.currentTheme) {
        if (this.tvWidget._ready) {
          this.tvWidget.changeTheme(this.props.currentTheme);
        }
      }
    }, 7000);
  }
  chartReady = (lang) => {

    const widgetOptions = {
      symbol:
        this.props && this.state.currentStock
          ? this.state.currentStock
          : this.props.currentStock,

      datafeed: new window.Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed(
        `${this.props.datafeedUrl}/api/chart/${
          this.props.currentLanguage ? this.props.currentLanguage : lang
        }`
      ),

      interval: this.props.interval,
      container: this.props.containerId,
      library_path: this.props.libraryPath,

      locale:
        lang != undefined
          ? lang
          : this.props && this.state.currentLanguage
          ? this.state.currentLanguage
          : this.props.currentLanguage,
      charts_storage_url: `${this.props.chartsStorageUrl}api/chart/${
        // /api
        this.props.currentLanguage ? this.props.currentLanguage : lang
      }`,
      charts_storage_api_version: this.props.chartsStorageApiVersion,
      client_id: this.props.clientId,
      user_id: this.state.userId || this.props.userId,
      fullscreen: this.props.fullscreen,
      autosize: this.props.autosize,
      theme: this.props.currentTheme,
      load_last_chart: true,
      studies_overrides: this.props.studiesOverrides,
      enabled_features: ["study_templates"],
      disabled_features: ["control_bar"],

      custom_indicators_getter: function (PineJS) {
        return Promise.resolve([
          {
            name: "RSI Indicator",
            metainfo: {
              _metainfoVersion: 51,
              id: "RSIIndicator@tv-basicstudies-1",
              description: "Relative Strength Index Indicator",
              shortDescription: "RSI",
              is_price_study: false,
              isCustomIndicator: true,
              plots: [
                {
                  id: "plot_0",
                  type: "line",
                },
                {
                  id: "plot_1",
                  type: "line",
                },
                {
                  id: "plot_2",
                  type: "colorer",
                  target: "filledAreaId1",
                  palette: "paletteId1",
                },
              ],

              filledAreas: [
                {
                  id: "filledAreaId1",
                  objAId: "plot_0",
                  objBId: "plot_1",
                  title: "Filled area between first and second plot",
                  type: "plot_plot",
                  palette: "paletteId1",
                },
              ],

              palettes: {
                paletteId1: {
                  valToIndex: {
                    0: 0,
                    1: 1,
                  },
                  colors: {
                    0: {
                      name: "First color",
                    },
                    1: {
                      name: "Second color",
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
              defaults: {
                filledAreasStyle: {
                  filledAreaId1: {
                    color: "yellow",
                    visible: true,
                    transparency: 40,
                  },
                },

                palettes: {
                  paletteId1: {
                    colors: {
                      0: {
                        color: "green",
                        width: 1,
                        style: 0,
                      },
                      1: {
                        color: "blue",
                        width: 3,
                        style: 1,
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },

                styles: {
                  plot_0: {
                    linestyle: 1,
                    visible: true,
                    linewidth: 1,
                    plottype: 2,
                    trackPrice: true,
                    color: "blue",
                  },
                  plot_1: {
                    linestyle: 1,
                    visible: true,
                    linewidth: 2,
                    plottype: 2,
                    trackPrice: true,
                    color: "red",
                  },
                },
                precision: 4,
                inputs: {
                  integer: 14,
                },
              },
              styles: {
                plot_0: {
                  title: "First plot",
                  histogramBase: 0,
                },
                plot_1: {
                  title: "Second plot",
                  histogramBase: 0,
                },
              },
              inputs: [
                {
                  id: "integer",
                  name: "integer",
                  type: "integer",
                  defval: 14,
                  min: 14,
                  step: 1,
                },
              ],
              format: {
                type: "price",
                precision: 4,
              },
            },


            constructor: function () {
                //I want to access here in this constructor function
                this.data = [];
                this.closePrice = [];
                this.rsiLength = 14; // Default RSI period
                
                console.log(this.state)

              this.init = async function (context, inputCallback) {
                // Fetch data from the API
                console.log(this.state.currentStock)
                const result = await getIndicatorsData(this.props.currentStock,'TASI')
                this.data = result;
                console.log("data from api:", data);
              };


              this.main = function (context, inputCallback) {
                this.data.forEach((item) => {
                  if (haveSameDate(context.symbol.time, item.t)) {
                    console.log("have same date");
                    closePrice.push(item.c);
                  }
                });
                if (closePrice.length >= rsiLength) {
                  // Calculate RSI using the specified period
                  console.log("close price:", closePrice);

                  const rsi = calculateRSI(closePrice, rsiLength);
                  return rsi;
                }
              };
            },
          },
        ]);
      },
    };



     const haveSameDate = (timestamp1, timestamp2) => {
       const date1 = new Date(timestamp1);
       const date2 = new Date(timestamp2);
       return (
         date1.getUTCFullYear() === date2.getUTCFullYear() &&
         date1.getUTCMonth() === date2.getUTCMonth() &&
         date1.getUTCDate() === date2.getUTCDate()
       );
     };
     const calculateRSI = (prices) => {
       var gains = [];
       var losses = [];
       var period = 14;

       for (var i = 1; i < prices.length; i++) {
         var priceChange = prices[i] - prices[i - 1];
         console.log("price change:", priceChange);
         if (priceChange > 0) {
           gains.push(priceChange);
           losses.push(0);
         } else {
           gains.push(0);
           losses.push(-priceChange);
         }
       }

       var avgGain = gains.slice(-14).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 14;
       var avgLoss = losses.slice(-14).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 14;
       if (avgLoss === 0) {
         var rsi = 100; // Set RSI to 100 for this case
       } else {
         var rs = avgGain / avgLoss;
         console.log("RS:", rs);
         var rsi = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs);
       }

       var colorIndex = rsi > 70 ? 0 : rsi < 30 ? 1 : 0;

       return [0, rsi, colorIndex];
     };



  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TVChartContainer);
```